# C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver subfolders needed after install?

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card

I have Windows installed on a 60GB partition, that size is a snugger fit than I intended and now I find myself scraping for space.

One folder I've found that is relatively large is C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver.

```
C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver>du -q -v | find /V "\320.18\" | find /V "\314.22\" | find /V "\314.07\"  | find /V "\301.42\"  | find /V "\285.62\" | find /V "\280.26\"
 | find /V "\275.33\"
     217á203  C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\275.33
     219á105  C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\280.26
     282á306  C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\285.62
     212á677  C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\301.42
     226á488  C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\314.07
     226á862  C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\314.22
     259á739  C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\320.18

Totals:
Files:        1307
Directories:  112
Size:         1á683á847á581 bytes
Size on disk: 1á687á273á472 bytes
```

Are the folders only used to extract the driver installers before/during installation and therefore safe to delete? Or are they used even after the driver has been installed?

As a side note, if someone know a more efficient way to filter the output from du I'd like to know that aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are safe to delete, only used while installing.